# Scrollbar push to top when the size of the element reduces and transition applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a `navbar`, which have different UI looks while scrolling the page and when at the top of the page.

Problem - Everything is fine if I go through the mouse scrolling but get little weird when I use my `keyboard-down` button.
I am trying to replicate my problem in the below snippet and will explain what I believe is the exact problem.

**I am attaching a jsfiddle link** - https://jsfiddle.net/o3pLb9y2/4/

```js
const ThrottleUpdateHeader = _.throttle(updateHeader, 300)
document.addEventListener('scroll', ThrottleUpdateHeader, false)

function updateHeader() {
 let navbar = document.querySelector('nav')
  if(window.pageYOffset > 0) {
   navbar.classList = 'navbar--scrolling'
  } else {
  console.log(window.pageYOffset)
   navbar.classList = 'navbar'
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 1.875rem 0.984rem;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navbar--scrolling {
  padding: 0.534rem 0.984rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  Hello world
</nav>

<p>
  Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
</p>
```

I am not sure why `lodash` function is not working here in the stackoverflow snippet, added CDN.

Now when you see the fiddle I want you to press  `key-down` button single time and you will get the weird behaviour - `It changes to scrolling nav, but then moved back to initial Nav also feel like blocking if I press button not that frequently`.

**I know why this is happening** - When I press the `key-down` the `pageYoffset` get value changed and greater than `0` which triggers my function. But the moment new navbar appears it actually small in size as `padding` value get reduced, which again reduces the `pageYoffset` triggers the scroll function again and this time my `pageYoffset` is now `zero` again.

I was looking for a solution here. Thanks

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Comment: No! I cannot 

Comment: I don’t think this is an actual issue of scrolling via mouse wheel vs via cursor keys per se; Scrolling via the cursor keys just scrolls the page by a smaller amount, so the change in page layout that happens when the navigation switches position and/or height has an effect then, but not if the initial scroll covered a bigger distance already. If you can switch to position:fixed (and apply that for both states), it will avoid that issue, because the navigation won’t effect the rest of the page layout any more.

Comment: But again, If i use the element as `fixed` it will not settle the actual flow and behave as per the window reference, which will more likely create issues

Comment: It is not clear from your reduced example, whether you actually need `sticky` behavior. The overlap of a `fixed` navbar with the content can be countered by an appropriate padding-top on the body.